# SQL If field is '*' then select from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement

I have a table with the name "order". There is a field with 1 character with the name adressFinder('*', '%', '+') in my table. If there is a '+' I want to Select the field "adress" from the table "customer". If there is a '%' I want to Select "adress" from the table "customerTwo" and if there is a '+' then select "adress" from the table "customerThree".

All tables can be joined with the field "customerID".

I tried something like this but doesnt work(syntax problem):

```
Select order.orderId, order.customerID,
CASE WHEN order.adressFinder = '*' THEN (SELECT customer.adress FROM customer INNER JOIN order on (customer.customerID = order.customerID)) 
     WHEN order.adressFinder = '%' THEN (SELECT customer.adress FROM customerTwo INNER JOIN order on (customerTwo.customerID = order.customerID)) 
     WHEN order.adressFinder = '+' THEN (SELECT customer.adress FROM customerThree INNER JOIN order on (customerThree.customerID = order.customerID))
END
FROM order
INNER JOIN customer on (order.customerID = customer.customerID)
INNER JOIN customerTwo on (order.customerID = customerTwo.customerID) 
INNER JOIN customerThree on (order.customerID = customerThree.customerID)
```

Can somebody help me with my problem? Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with LEFT JOIN. Assuming you only want to show one address, you can use **COALESCE** - it will show the first non-null value as the address.

For example:

```
SELECT
o.orderId AS orderId, 
o.customerID AS customerID,
COALESCE(c.adress, c2.adress, c3.adress) AS Address
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.customerID = o.customerID AND o.adressFinder = '*'
LEFT JOIN customerTwo c2 ON c2.customerID = o.customerID AND o.adressFinder = '%'
LEFT JOIN customerThree c3 ON c3.customerID = o.customerID AND o.adressFinder = '+'
```

Comment: That helped me a lot, but is there a way to do it, if there is another field with the characters(*,%,+) and you have to do it again?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using subqueries.  Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT o.orderId, o.customerID,
       COALESCE(c.address, c2.address, c3.address)
FROM order o LEFT JOIN
     customer c
     ON o.customerID = c.customerID AND
        o.adressFinder = '*' LEFT JOIN
     customerTwo c2
     ON o.customerID = c2.customerID AND
        o.adressFinder = '%' LEFT JOIN
     customerThree c3
     ON o.customerID = c3.customerID AND
        o.adressFinder = '+';
```